# vscode unexpected token ( in hello world - C code

Tags: c, unexpected-token

I feel really stupid but this is the first time dealing with C for a basic CS course.
I try to do everything but it keeps giving me a unexpected token when trying to run the code.

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main(void)
{
    puts("Hello World!");
}
```

even using printf and \n at the end, same result, always unexpected token, what am I missing?
I've coded some complex javascript stuff before but this made me feel like a noob TT

[image]

Comment: You're trying to execute a C file in a shell (bash or sh, I guess). The first line is interpreted as comment, the second line isn't valid shell code. You need to compile the code first. BTW: Don't add pictures of text, copy'n'paste the text instead.

Comment: Thanks, sorrry about the picture, I am kinda new posting here

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should compile your code and then run the obtained executable. Install [gcc](https://gcc.gnu.org/) and run

```bash
gcc -Wall -Wextra -pedantic ./hello.c -o hello
```

This will produce a binary file named "hello". Then you can run

```bash
./hello
```

and "Hello World!" will be printed to the screen.

Comment: @ikegami Thanks! I updated my answer according to your suggestions.

Comment: it did work! Thanks! But what about using make to compile? Why did the person in the course use make and it worked but not for me?

Comment: @MARIANCE Re "*But what about using make to compile*", If you have problems creating a `Makefile`, ask a question about that.

Comment: @MARIANCE And it would be `make hello`, not `make hello.c`, since `hello` is the file you are trying to make

Comment: @MARIANCE Make is just a (great) utility that allows you to specify compilation instructions and dependencies in order to make your life easier. Under the hood, the compilation command remains the same. Your Makefile should contain an instruction that specifies the name of the binary (hello), the name of the source code file (hello.c) and the compilation command. Then you'll be able to run `make hello` and Make will know that it needs to run the compilation command when the code in hello.c changes.

Refer to [Make docs](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/) for more info.